# HighCharts xAxis - tickInterval for month

Tags: highcharts

Am trying to plot spline graph for the *no of passed/failed testcases* and grouping them based on **hour/date/month/year** and I am getting this value as irregular series *(i.e) if its hours, datas won't be available for all 24 hours. Its the same case for other groupings*. As the datas are irregular need the x-axis tick interval to be month vice, Have tried using the dateTimeLabelFormats, It didn't help me much as its only formats the label.

All i need is the tickInterval needs to be month vice and both date&time in tooltip.

Sorry that i won't be able to post data/fiddle as am using this HighCharts in an BI tool(SpagoBI) and it requires templates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have tried using the both dateTimeLableFormats to format the HOUR and tickInterval, but not met my requirement

Comment: can you post your code along with the json?

Comment: Am using BI tool SpagoBI, so it requires only templates and DS, So i dont have datas in json format. Am pasting my Dataset below.  [{45, 0, 1388082600000},{57, 1, 1388082600000},{30, 0, 1387996200000},{78, 0, 1387996200000},{33, 0, 1387996200000}]

Comment: As per my knowledge you need to have json.

Answer (score 4):

I simply used a `minTickInterval` of 28 days to account for short Feb months. The `tickIntervals` automatically adjust to 1 month.

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  minTickInterval: 28*24*3600*1000
}
```

Works great for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, setting ordinal false fixes the time intervals and not changed for best visualization.

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    minTickInterval: 3600*24*30*1000,//time in milliseconds
    minRange: 3600*24*30*1000,
    ordinal: false //this sets the fixed time formats                        
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the data that you are passing in javascript.

Before going further check this [Preprocessing Data for highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-database) link and make sure you are doing it in right way

Answer (score 0):

You need to have sorted data via x ascending, as I see you have incorrect format of that. In case when you need to customise tooltip content or label on axis, you can use formatter.

[Tooltip formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter)

[Label formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter)

[Date format](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.dateFormat)

Answer (score -1):

What I did was subtracting the date format for month which is m-1. 
If you have Y,m,d 
change to Y,m-1,d

This is from php to js

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you make an attempt to answer a question make sure it is of [good quality](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). As far as I can see this might be a correct answer, but there is just to few information to figure that out. Good answers often contain some code examples that help explain what you mean.