# Highcharts TickInterval months, days, weeks

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

Building linear graph of date range with three options for the plot in days, weeks, and months. The data is supplied correspondingly with start of the date for days option, start of the week for weeks options, start of the month for months option. I am unable to set the tick interval with proper intervals as the interval of months vary 31 days for some months, 30 days for some months, 28/29 for some months.

I could set the intervals properly for the other two options but for months I couldn't as the interval varies depending on the period.

Is there anyway I could force the Highchart to plot all the values in X-axis, I pass in as data, so that I can ignore tickInterval parameter.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20795975/3898339) may help

Comment: You can define custom ticks with [axis.tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions) option. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/tickpositions-tickpositioner/